# Entity Framework select sum specific column child table that have many to many relation and is not numeric

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this class

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace IVF_EHR.Models
    {
        public class SemenProcess
        {
            public Guid SemenProcessID { get; set; }

            public virtual List<CollectionMethod> CollectionMethods { get; set; }

            public SemenProcess()
            {
                SemenProcessID = Guid.NewGuid();
                CollectionMethods = new List<CollectionMethod>();
            }

        }
    }
```

as you see this class have relation width this class

```
            using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors;

    namespace IVF_EHR.Models
    {
        public class CollectionMethod
        {

            [Key]
            public int CollectionMethodID { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [MaxLength(50)]
            public string Title { get; set; }

            public virtual List<SemenProcess> SemenProcesss { get; set; }

            public CollectionMethod()
            {
                CollectionMethodID = 0;
                Title = "";
                SemenProcesss = new List<SemenProcess>();
            }

        }
    }
```

The relation between this 2 class is many to many.
i need to write a one linq query with good performance that doing this

```
select dbo.GetWokeTitle(s.SemenProcessID)[woleTitle] , * from [SemenProcesses] [s]
```

and `dbo.GetWokeTitle` is like this

```
    CREATE FUNCTION GetWokeTitle
    (
        @SemenProcessID uniqueidentifier 
    )
    RETURNS nvarchar(max)
    AS
    BEGIN
        declare @result nvarchar(max)

        set @result = '';
        select @result = @result + title  from [SemenProcessCollectionMethods] [sc] inner join [CollectionMethods] [c] on c.[CollectionMethodID]=sc.[CollectionMethod_CollectionMethodID]
        where sc.SemenProcess_SemenProcessID=@SemenProcessID

        -- Return the result of the function
        RETURN @result

    END
    GO
```

I use ADO.NET Entity Framework, and I need to write a linq query that does the same as the above SQL code.
and one more thing 
i cant execute .ToList() for performance issues , i need to produce one query Without execute that query . Actually i have a control that control use query not object list and that control execute query by itself .
i can create view and use that view in entity but i want some thing else , that is may last way

Comment: You have posted too much code. It's so confusing. Just posting some code to show the relationship between the two entities, and the properties that are needed for the query would have been enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I recommend. Create a ViewModel like this:

```
public class SemenProcessViewModel
{
  public string WokeTitle { get; set; }
  public SemenProcess SemenProcess { get; set; }
}
```

Then, your linq query will be something like this:

```
var semenProcessViewModel = db.SemenProcesses
   .Where(s => s.SemenProcessID == semenProcessID).ToList()
   .Select(s => new SemenProcessViewModel {
       SemenProcess = s,
       WokeTitle = string.Join("", s.CollectionMethods.Select(c => c.Title))
   }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: tank you for your time

Comment: tank you for your time but i have one problem , i cant execute .ToList() for performance issues , i need to produce one query Without execute that query . Actually i have a control that control use query not object list and that control execute query by itself

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if I understand what you need, but if performance is an issue for you, the best thing you can do is to create a stored procedure in your database, and call it from your controller.

Comment: this is what you do var ListOBj = (from item in db.itemlist select item).tolist()

Comment: this is what i need var Query = from item in db.itemlist select item

Comment: i can solve may problem width view but i need to do this project width just entity frame work

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I don't think the string.Join method works without .ToList().

Comment: @ataravati It does not.

Comment: yes you right i try , It does not. i Waste my whole time on this problem , i dont Think any solution exiting for this problem in entity frame work 5

Comment: Well, the solution exists. The problem is that you can't use `ToList()` for performance issues. I still recommend that you create a stored procedure in your database, and create a function import in your entity framework model, and map it to your stored procedure.

Comment: i never use some thing like this , can you show me an example